# What is the best practice on remote branch merging?

Tags: git, github

I'm currently developing an open-source project but I don't have that much expertise with **GitHub**.
I'm using GitFlow extension and I want to protect develop branch so that it is only possible to merge a feature with it via a `pull-request`. With that being said, I have 5 questions:

1. How should I protect `develop` branch in GitHub?
2. What else should I consider in the open-source development world in regards to git?
3. Can I and should I protect `develop` and `master` branches from myself?
4. Who's responsible for the creation of `release` branches?
5. Is there something that I'm missing? What else should I consider?

Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I protect develop branch in GitHub?

GitHub has settings to protect branches. You can find how in their documentation with a quick google search.

> Can I and should I protect develop and master branches from myself?

Yes. This can prevent you from making mistakes.

> Who's responsible for the creation of release branches?

If you are the only one working on this project, then you create the release branches. If you have other people working with you, then you can delegate this to anyone you trust to prepare the release.